# Etymology of impersonal pronoun "one"

Tags: english, etymology, pronouns

The 'impersonal' pronoun in Germanic and Romance languages seems to come from one of two paths:

**Cognate with the word for 'man'**

- Proto-Germanic: **mann-*

  - Dutch: ***men***
  - German: ***man***
  - Old English: ***man*** <sub>(< *mann*)</sub>
- Latin: *homō*

  - French: ***on*** <sub>(< *om* < *hom*) [use infl. by germanic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on#Etymology_9)</sub>
  - Catalan: ***hom*** <sub>(< home) [infl. by germanic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hom#Etymology_2)</sub>

**Cognate with the word for 'one' (number)**

- PIE: **óynos*

  - German: ***einer***
  - Latin: *ūnus*

    - Spanish: ***uno***
    - Asturian: ***ún, unu***

Is the English impersonal pronoun 'one' derived from the English word for the number, or from French *on* (as [suggested by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_(pronoun)#Etymology) the OED)?

Comment: Why the downvote? Both top voted comments on the current meta thread say that etymology questions like this are fine for this SE: https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1838/the-need-for-changing-our-guidelines-for-etymology-questions

Comment: Most probably because of that guy. Don't take it personally, I think this community is pretty fed up by now. Have a +1 to counter it.

Comment: Here is what the OED actually has to say about the etymology of 'one' as a pronoun: "**The use as an indefinite generic pronoun (sense C. 17), which replaced *me pron.2*, *men pron.* in late Middle English, may have been influenced by Anglo-Norman *hom* , *on* , *un* , Old French, Middle French *on* (12th cent.; mid 9th cent. in form *om* ; French *on* ; ultimately < classical Latin *homō* : see *homo n.1*), though this is not regarded as a necessary influence by some scholars.**"

Comment: ...so the OED's claim is less that is was *derived* From french *on* so much as potenially *influenced by* it.

Comment: Well, one has to wonder in the first place, why \ainaz went to *one*, while *a* ~ *an*, Nl. *een*, Ger. *ein-* went a different way, supposedly from the same root.

Comment: The corresponding ordinal \*frumo "first" maybe notable in light of Ger. *man*, Lat.  *homo*, comparing German *Frau* "woman, (titular) miss, Mrs.". If I remember correctly, she is allegedly from a similar root, analogous to e.g. *prince* (prime).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For posterity, I am copying the content of Mark Beadles' comment to an answer. It seems there is no consensus among etymologists as to whether there was French influence in its development:

> The use as an indefinite generic pronoun (sense C. 17), which replaced *me* pron.<sup>2</sup>, *men* pron. in late Middle English, may have been influenced by Anglo-Norman *hom, on, un,* Old French, Middle French *on* (12th cent.; mid 9th cent. in form *om*; French *on*; ultimately < classical Latin *homō*: see *homo* n.<sup>1</sup>), **though this is not regarded as a necessary influence by some scholars.**
>
> - *The Oxford English Dictionary*, second edition (1989)

Comment: @ukemi Don't know about Spanish, but in Italian, *uno* can be used as an impersonal pronoun. There are alternative constructions, mainly one with "si" which resembles a reflexive verb, and English impersonal *one* sounds natural when you translate it into *uno* only in certain contexts, but still.

Comment: @LjL yep it's the same in Spanish, with *uno* and *se*.